# Gatsby build process and window/document

Tags: gatsby

So I get using window/document can cause problems because `gatsby build` is running the application server side and therefore `window` isn't available, as detailed [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

That's fine, but I have two, closely related questions:

1) What is Gatsby actually doing when I run `gatsby build`? The obvious answer is "turning React into HTML," but what does that mean? Why does it run the application at all?

2) Is it entirely safe to use `window` in my application, so long as I if-check every instance? I ask because I've noticed that passing an `undefined` to a component that was expecting data from `window` during build will break that component in the HTML (for reasons that would be difficult to explain in a SO question)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. `gatsby build` generates the static html, javascript and other files that make up your production site.
   Once the build finishes, you can review the output files in the `/public/` directory, and you should be able to host this directory as-is on any standard web server.
2. `window` is not defined during the build process, there is no window at that stage. `window` **is** defined when the site loads on the client browser.

The simplest way to access `window` in the `gatsby-browser.js` file, which only get's loaded when the browser and window are present.

If you need to access it from a component you could use the `useEffect` hook,
for example:

```
useEffect(() => {       
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
       // Window does not exist on SSR
    }
  }, [])
```

***Note:** only checking if `window !== undefined` may not do what you expect, window may evaluate to 'undefined' if you check too soon, using react useeffect hook ensures you are checking for the window object after if got a chance to load*